# Text Services Framework failed to set global compartment value as VT_BSTR

Tags: com, text-services-framework

I wrote a test application (.exe) for inter-process communication using TSF global compartment and the following code works correctly when the variant type is VT_I4, but for VT_BSTR the ITfCompartment::SetValue return S_FALSE and the OnChange callback is not fired on the text service (an IME).

The S_FALSE for ITfCompartment::SetValue is not even documented on MSDN and I guess that means the operation succeeded but has no effect.

Can anyone offer some ideas as to how to solve this problem? Thanks!

```
ITfThreadMgr *pThreadMgr;
if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TF_ThreadMgr, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ITfThreadMgr, (void **)&pThreadMgr)))
{
    return;
}

if (FAILED(pThreadMgr->Activate(&m_tfClientID)))
{
    return;
}

ITfCompartmentMgr *pCompartmentMgr;
if (pThreadMgr->GetGlobalCompartment(&pCompartmentMgr) != S_OK)
{
    return;
}

ITfCompartment *pCompartment;
if (pCompartmentMgr->GetCompartment(TheGlobalCompartmentGUID, &pCompartment) != S_OK)
{
    pCompartment = nullptr;
    pCompartmentMgr->Release();
    return;
}

VARIANT varValue;
varValue.vt = VT_BSTR;
varValue.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"abc");
//varValue.vt = VT_I4;
//varValue.lVal = 1;

HRESULT hr = pCompartment->SetValue(m_tfClientID, &varValue);
if (hr != S_OK)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"SetValue failed");
}

pCompartment->Release();
pCompartmentMgr->Release();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can only store integers in global compartments.  Marshaling a string or object is not possible given how TSF global compartments work (it runs below the COM marshaling layer).